# can someone help me to solve,prove this identites

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1+\cos (2x)}{\cos (2x)}\cdot\frac{1+\cos (4x)}{\sin (4x)}=\cot (x)$$ 
I made $\cos 4x=\cos 2(2x)$ and $\sin 4x = \sin 2(2x)$ but I don't know what to do more?? Can someone help me on solving this math homework?

Comment: I re-formatted the math using TeX. Please double-check that I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to do the cos(4x)??

Comment: Use  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider the double angle identities:

$\cos{2x} = \cos^2{x} - \sin^2{x}$

$\sin{2x} = 2\sin{x}\cos{x}$